# Android ListVIew set view to a particular row

Tags: android, listview

i have a list of songs displayed on a listview.
On click of any row player activity starts and the song is played.
If user press back key then i want the list to start from the previously selected row. Position of all the row should remain same only the selected row should be the first one to be displayed.

Comment: which array you use i mean Vector or List for listiew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set selection everytime:This works after setting adapter.I using ListActivity here.

```
public class TestList extends ListActivity
{

    String str[]=new String[100];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) 
    {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            str[i]="Android# "+i;
        }
        getListView().setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str));
        getListView().setSelection(50);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the current playing song position in application memory and use

```
list.setSelection(position);
```

when you return back to the activity.